# Collective Article timeline group name leads to 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives

Steps to reproduce:

1. View a random article from a random collective
2. Go to the timeline of the article

E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68443539/timeline

Notice the start of the post's history:

> Jul 19 at 15:55 | history | notice added | Google Cloud | Answer by Recognized
> Member/Admin

The group name "Google Cloud" is clickable, but leads to a 404: https://stackoverflow.com/users/groups/-1002

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! The team will have a look, and we'll update this post when it's fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much like the "[Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)" user, each Collective has a user group associated with it that can be associated to automated tasks.  In this specific case, it was associated with the tagging of an article as being written by a Recognized Member or Admin member of the Google Cloud Collective.

Since there isn't actually a user profile to link to in these cases, we've chosen to have the link point to the Collective landing page instead.  This change went live this morning.

Thanks again for reporting this!